# HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject and HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to use these two functions in case when you have all your resources for a mvc 3 site in a seperate class library project or is this strickly fixed only on App_LocalResources default folder in a project.

I know that GetLocalResourcesObject has a parameter virtualPath. Is it possible to set this path to another class library?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx voor an explanation on how to extend the Resource-Provider Model

Comment: Tnx...I don't know how I missed that